# Starting a Spring web app and can't get JSP content routed to localhost

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've got what is probably an embarassing issue trying to get started with Spring shown below is the code I have.

HelloController.java

```html
package hello;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/zz")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
     return "welcome";
    }
    

}
```

Application.java

```html
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

 @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
 
 
 
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("started");
          
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp

```html
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample Application JSP Page</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor=white>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td align=center>
        <img src="images/springsource.png">
      </td>
      <td>
         <h1>Sample Application JSP Page</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br />
  <p>This is the output of a JSP page that is part of the HelloWorld application.</p>

  <%= new String("Hello!") %>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I visit localhost:8080 I get simply a white screen with the string "welcome" printed. It seems Spring isn't able to find the jsp with my mappings.

My welcome.jsp file is under projectroot->WEB-INF->welcome.jsp. Apologies if this could be resolved with a search but it seems most other issues with this have a setup using a web.xml to define the routing to the server. I do not think this is true in my case.. but I'd be glad if someone could prove me wrong.

-----Edit----
as kamoor has been suggesting the directory structure was off. I updated the structure and placed the jsp and it is now been routed correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating a jar?

Comment: Not at the moment.. although I'm sure it could come up as a pain point later on. For now I am just trying to get the jsp to display locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you need to do with JSP in spring boot application.

First of all fix the code as below

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
}
}
```

Next, if you are creating final runnable "jar" there are restrictions around how Servlet container try to find resources in embedded jar. See this [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) to start with.

One work around is keep JSP files in resource folder (public folder for example) and create a runnable war artifact instead of jar artifact.

Or you can create jar file but create directory structure as META-INF/resources/jsp/

See sample [project](https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat7-jsp-jar)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. IGave it a shot but now localhost:8080 is showing a 404.

Comment: Can you please share your project structure. Or refer my sample app https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample  look for JSPController

Comment: projectroot->WEB-INF is a wrong directory. See documentation or sample app I posted

Comment: I've actually just tried copying the jsp into pretty much every possible directory I could think of but it still won't pick it up for some reason. Attached is the project structure edited into the post. Thanks again for taking a look and I'll look through your sample to check out what could be up.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems I need 10 reputation to post an image of the project structure so it may not be possible just yet :/

Comment: I updated the structure based on this and all  is well.

Answer (score 2):

change `@RestController` to `@Controller`

Comment: Still getting more of the same with that update.. I didn't realize I may have specified a REST only app though! Thanks